# Mysql Replication trigger not executing on slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication

Mixed replication is enabled.

MySQL master has a table Products that has triggers on update and delete. On slave database we have different trigger on same table on update and delete.

Master database trigger executing properly but slave db trigger not executing. Is there any way we can achieve this. Slave db trigger we dont want on master db.

Comment: In the mixed replication mode some events are statement-based, some are row-based. Row-based events will not trigger any triggers when applied. You need to switch to SBR if you need triggers on the slave side.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason when mixed binary log format the statement-based replication is converted to row-based replication.

Here, I think it matches to your case :

> [When one or more tables with AUTO_INCREMENT columns are updated and a
> trigger or stored function is invoked. Like all other unsafe
> statements, this generates a warning if binlog_format = STATEMENT.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-mixed.html)

Hope this resolves your query.